# How to get multiple IDs on click from table row?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I want to get multiple IDs for delete method, I have a table, each cell has different Id I need to get those IDs and be able to delete them one by one. So there are 5 columns, 5 different IDs in one row here is my code what I tried to do:

Controller:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("MIDKalorimetar/Delete/{Id:int}/{Id2:int}/{Id3:int}/{Id4:int}/{Id5:int}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int Id, int Id2, int Id3, int Id4, int Id5)
    {
        var model = await _db.ParametriMjerila.Where(x => x.Id == Id && x.Id == Id2 && x.Id == Id3 && x.Id == Id4 && x.Id == Id5).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

        return PartialView("Delete", model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(DeleteKalorimetarVM parametrniMjerila)
    {
        var model = await _db.ParametriMjerila.Where(x => x.Id == parametrniMjerila.Id).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        _db.ParametriMjerila.Remove(model);
        _db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index", model);
    }
```

Index.cshtml:

```
 <tbody style="text-align:center;">
                
        @{
            for(int x = 0; x < Model.NajveciBrojElemenata; x++){
                <tr id="@Model.Id">
                        <td>@Model.Qi.ElementAtOrDefault(x)?.VrijednostKarakteristike</td>
                        <td>@Model.Qp.ElementAtOrDefault(x)?.Opis</td>
                        <td>@Model.Qs.ElementAtOrDefault(x)?.VrijednostKarakteristike</td>
                        <td>@Model.R.ElementAtOrDefault(x)?.VrijednostKarakteristike</td>
                        <td>@Model.SP.ElementAtOrDefault(x)?.VrijednostKarakteristike</td>
                  
                        @if (dozvoliEdit)
                        {
                            <td style="width:20%">
                                <button class="bg-transparent border-0" style=" background: transparent; border: 0; border: 0 !important; " data-toggle="ajax-modal" data-url="@Url.Action($"Details/")">
                                    <img src="/images/detailsPng.png" width="25" height="25">
                                </button>                           

                                <button class="bg-transparent border-0" style=" background: transparent; border: 0; border: 0 !important; " data-toggle="ajax-modal" data-url="@Url.Action($"Uredi/")">
                                    <img src="/images/editPng.png" width="25" height="25">
                                </button>  
                                <button class="bg-transparent border-0" style=" background: transparent; border: 0; border: 0 !important; " data-toggle="ajax-modal" data-url="@Url.Action($"Delete/{@Model.Id}")">
                                    <img src="/images/deletePng.png" width="25" height="25">
                                </button>  
                            </td>
                        }

            </tr>
            }
   
     }
        </tbody>
```

View model for Index.cshtml:

```
 public int[] Id { get; set; }
    public List<ParametarMjerila> IDs { get; set; }
    public List<ParametarMjerila> Qp { get; set; }
    public List<ParametarMjerila> Qi { get; set; }
    public List<ParametarMjerila> R { get; set; }
    public List<ParametarMjerila> Qs { get; set; }
    public List<ParametarMjerila> SP { get; set; }
    public int NajveciBrojElemenata
    {
        get; set;
    } = 16;
```

How to pass those IDs to data-url="@Url.Action($"Delete/{@Model.Id}")" to open modal delete. The error I get is 405 I cant pass IDs

Answer (score 0):

I see your action Delete is async Task so you need to await the database query too

```
await _db.ParametriMjerila.Remove(model);
await _db.SaveChanges();
```

But I also advise you to move all your logic to a service class.

Comment: what about Url.Action how do I pass IDs?